# Subsequent method calls to same method enters a new context?

Tags: c#

I have a question regarding method calls and stack pointers.

Basically I have a program that reads input from the user. After creating an object of a class "Input", a method call "prompt()" presents a menu with choices, and each choice you make calls a new method that performs some operations. After making a choice, you can always choose to go back to the main menu, and this action calls "prompt()" again.

Now, my question is, will each call of "prompt()" point to a new place in the memory stack or will it enter the same context as when the first call was made? I.e is it possible to create a memory leak by going back to the main menu over and over?

```
class inOut {

public string[] Prompt(){
   ...
   presentChoices();
   ...
}

private void PresentChoices(){
   ...
   if(someChoice){
       manualInput();
   }
   ...
}

private void ManualInput(){
   ...
   if(goBack){
       Prompt();
   }
   ...
}
```

}

I hope the question was clear and thanks in advance for any answers on this!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. The consensus here is that [tags should not be included in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), so I have edited the title.

Comment: I guess it all depends on how you are doing it. You should include some of your code that shows this

Answer (score 0):

For each method you enter there should be a corresponding `return`. Otherwise it may lead to `StackOverlow`. It's not a new *context*, but a values left in stack, which are used for `return` to return to the point where method was called and for method call itself (to pass parameters).

To have something *repeating itself* you can use infinite loop:

```
while(true)
{
    ... // repeat this action

    if(endcondition)
        break;
}
```

In your case repeated action is call to `prompt()` to show menu. It may have return value to tell whenever repeat or exit, which you use in `endcondition`.

Comment: *If* the `endcondition` happens to be at the bottom of the loop "body" (the block over which you loop), use a `do` statement.

Answer (score 0):

As Long as you call the method on the same object instance, it's going to be the same pointer to the same adress.

When you create new instances of an object each object has it's own pointer. 
If you want to avoid that then you need to define the method as static. In this case you will call the method not from an instance but from the type.

Something you need to be careful about especially when you call the same method over and over again from the same instance context are recursive calls. To many recursive calls (many thousands) will result in a StackOverFlowException (like the Name of this website). You can find out if you have recursive calls in the StackTrace pane in Visual Studio or if you have Resharper installed it will tell you on the left side of the document.

Either way, what you are describing here is not really a "Memory Leak" (ML's are unused objects that do not get collected and stay in memory not doing anything) but rather a stack Overflow Situation.

Comment: Thank you very much! I upvoted but it doesn't show my votes it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Objects that are not referenced anymore are garbage collected.Thats what will happen to your Input object.

Unlesss...

... you do it wrong.

In Winform applications doing it wrong usually happens when there are eventhandlers involved that for some reason (the publisher of the event lives longer than the subscriber) prevent the garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your code looks something like this:

```
void Prompt()
{
  // ...
  var obj = new Input();
  // ...
  if (someCondition)
  {
    Prompt(); // recursive
  }
  // ...
  // Is 'obj' used here?
}
```

Then when you call `Prompt()` recursively, yes, a new context is created. The `obj` variable will point to a new object, etc.

If the recursion becomes very, very deep, you might get a `StackOverflowException` (no more space on the stack for new "call frames"), or you might get an `OutOfMemoryException` (no more heap space for `Input` instances).

However, if you know for some reason that the recursion will not become too deep, the Garbage Collector will clean things for you when it is safe to do so.

But maybe you should consider a `while` (or `do`) loop instead of having your method call itself? It really depends on what you want to achieve.

---

I may have misunderstood your question. Maybe `Prompt()` is not called from within `Prompt` itself? You should give simplified structure of your code (like my code sample above) to make it clear what calls what from where.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Prompt() does not call itself directly, but rather calls another method that calls Prompt(). I'll update my post

Comment: @AlexWormbs In that case (if I read your comment correctly) you will still have recursion, and my answer still applies. Try running the code and have the debugger "break". You will see when you "step" along that the "Call Stack" (see the window with that name inside Visual Studio) grows for each times you re-enter `Prompt()`.